# EhCache 3.8.1 BootstrapCacheLoader

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-3, ehcache-2

I have a problem when using cache across different modules. At first, I was using Ehcache 2.10.6 so in my configuration `ehcache.xml` file I had something like this:

```
<bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
```

and I was using it as `cache.bootstrap();`

After upgrading to 3.x version (**3.8.1**) , this is not available nor I can see any replacements. Is there any replacement to do or something else to replicate the configuration above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI based replication has been discontinued in Ehcache 3.x. Its implementation in Ehcache 2.x was lacking in semantics: writes could be lost, reads were not guaranteed to be consistent, etc ...

Instead you should look into [cache clustering with Terracotta](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/clustered-cache.html).